# php send email with mail() function for email address out a domain

Tags: php, function, email

Through a simple mail script, I can not send emails to addresses outside the domain (gmail, mail.com, outlook, etc.), while I can send emails only to the domain's email as support@domain.com.

through the php mail() function I can not send emails to email addresses belonging to other domains.

## not send email to Gmail accounts

```
<?php
$to = 'alias@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test mail from domain.com';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: support@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: support@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

## work fine! send email to Domain.com accounts

```
<?php
$to = 'support@domain.com';
$subject = 'test mail from domain.com';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: support@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: support@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I try to resolve with this solutions but not work:
1. modifiy .htaccess to define SMTP address (example: mail.domain.com)
2. config a DBconnet.php with ini_set('SMTP', "mail.domain.com");
3. I have contact my hosting support but without a solution

How to resolve this problem?
Have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Spam filters are eating up your emails

Comment: is this live or on a wamp / local server?

Comment: try https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Have you try to add <> tags to the mail: $to = '<alias@gmail.com>'; and on other emails. ps: may be this can help you: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/send-emails-using-php-mail#gref

Comment: 1. spam filters are off
2. is live
3. in other domain with plesk, work fine without phpMailer

Comment: Not *your* spam filters. The spam filters at the ISPs who transport the email. I suspect you haven't set up domain keys or other spam prevention measures.